# What are Streaming API tokens in plotly?

Tags: python, api, token, plotly, data-visualization

Recently, I have been working on data visualization using plotly. I have created a plot and I need to make a new plot. I have created 2 Streaming API tokens and added them to credentials file. I don't have any idea what these streaming tokens actually do. Can I use different streaming tokens to stream different plots, if yes please explain me how? Can I use same streaming token on multiple traces? Also, I would like to know the purpose of streaming tokens in plotly.

plotly streaming in python : https://plot.ly/python/streaming-tutorial/

Initially, I have created a plot with one streaming API token. Now, I want to create another separate plot. I need to be sure that new plot will not override first plot and for that I think streaming tokens can be used, although not completely sure.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. The plot.ly page you've linked here states that `You will need one unique stream token for every trace object you wish to stream to. Thus if you have two traces that you want to plot and stream, you're going to require two unique stream tokens` and your question seems to be asking that very thing.

Comment: Stream_ID is the (Stream) Token you connected your data to. As @ChrisLarson outlined. One source requires one token and it is not possible to stream two sources via one token.

Answer (score 1):

Just to show you the work flow presented [here](https://plot.ly/python/streaming-tutorial/). It requires you to setup the two different streams within your Plotly user profile.

```
stream_ids = tls.get_credentials_file()['stream_ids']

# Get stream id from stream id list 
stream_id_1 = stream_ids[0]
stream_id_2 = stream_ids[1]


# Make instance of stream id object 
stream_1 = go.Stream(
    token=stream_id_1,  # link stream id to 'token' key
    maxpoints=80      # keep a max of 80 pts on screen
)

stream_2 = go.Stream(
    token=stream_id_2,  # link stream id to 'token' key
    maxpoints=80      # keep a max of 80 pts on screen
)

# Initialize trace of streaming plot by embedding the unique stream_id
trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=[],
    y=[],
    mode='lines+markers',
    stream=stream_1         # (!) embed stream id, 1 per trace

trace2 = go.Scatter(
    x=[],
    y=[],
    mode='lines+markers',
    stream=stream_2         # (!) embed stream id, 1 per trace
)
```

This should do the work for you. As mentioned before, it is neccessary to use an additionall stream for each additional plot you want to show.

Comment: Did this solved your question? @Kartikeya Sharma Please accept my answer then. :)